# Convert a nested dictionary into a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, recursion

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
Input = {
    'key1':{'key11':'val11', 'key12':'val12'},
    'key2':{'key21':{'key211':'val211', 'key212':'val212'}},
    'key3':'val3',
    'key4':{'key41':'val41', 'key42':'val42'}
}
```

Output =

1) When value is a dictionary, then create an output string variable =

```
key1 { key11 val11 key12 val12 } key2 { key21 { key211 val211 key212 val212 }} key4 { key41 val41 key42 val42}
```

2) When value is not a dictionary, then print `"just a string element"`

Below is my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def stringBuilder(dictionary):
    stringOption = ""
    innerString = ""
    # print dictionary
    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            stringBuilder(value)
        else:
            innerString = innerString + " " + str(key) + " " + str(value)
            print innerString
            stringOption = "{" + innerString + " }"
            print stringOption
    return stringOption

d = {'key1':{'key11':'val11', 'key12':'val12'}, 'key2':{'key21':{'key211':'val211', 'key212':'val212'}}, 'key3':'val3', 'key4':{'key41':'val41', 'key42':'val42'}}
print d
stringOption = ""
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        stringOption = stringOption + " " + str(key) + " " + stringBuilder(value)
        print stringOption
    else:
        print "just a string element"
print stringOption
```

Here is the output that I get:

```
{'key2': {'key21': {'key211': 'val211', 'key212': 'val212'}}}
 key211 val211
{ key211 val211 }
 key2 
 key2
```

Comment: If you wish to turn the dictionary into a string, just use `str(Input)`. Can you clarify your overall objective?

Comment: (!) Can you please give expected outputs? Also can you please improve formatting?

Comment: Why isn't `key3 val3` in your desired outcome for the first result?

Comment: This is not the value I get using Python 2.7; I get more tracing output and a final result that looks much more like what you want.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that want you remove `:,'` as well as standalone keys from a string representation of a dictionary?

Comment: Not gonna post as an answer because I may have misunderstood, but if what I said above is accurate, try using [`(,\s+'\w+':\s+'\w+',|[:',])`](https://regex101.com/r/8e7scS/2/) and `re.sub` to get what you want.

Comment: @chrisz: The main program explicitly discards `key3: val3`; it calls the function only for `dict` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you discard the returned string of your `dict` case:

```
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        stringBuilder(value)
```

Instead, try saving the value to pass back up the line:

```
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        stringOption = stringBuilder(value)
```

Resulting output:

```
key2 { key211 val211 key212 val212 } key1 { key12 val12 key11 val11 } key4 { key41 val41 key42 val42 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing your own implementation (unless that's what you want) why not use the [json library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)? You can extend JSONEncoder and JSONDecoder to suit your use case?

Answer (score 0):

A great recursion exercise!

```
def rec(x):
    # assuming values are either str or otherwise dict
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return x
    return '{' + ' '.join([k + ' ' + rec(v) for (k, v) in x.items()]) + '}'


Input = {
    'key1':{'key11':'val11', 'key12':'val12'},
    'key2':{'key21':{'key211':'val211', 'key212':'val212'}},
    'key3':'val3',
    'key4':{'key41':'val41', 'key42':'val42'}
}
```

Output:

```
In [6]: rec(Input)
Out[6]: '{key1 {key11 val11 key12 val12} key2 {key21 {key211 val211 key212 val212}} key3 val3 key4 {key41 val41 key42 val42}}'
```